# Best way to remove default IOS date picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, css, date

I currently have the jQuery datepicker implemented which is working great on all browsers but when I view in mobile (iPad) the IOS default date picker comes up too. What is the best way to remove it? CSS? change input type?

This is what my input element looks like:

```
<input type="date" name="payment_Received" class="form-control datepicker" />
<script>
    j$(document).ready(function(e) {
        j$('.datepicker').datepicker({
            dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd'   
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: How about using `type="text"` instead of `type="date"`?

Comment: Yeah good thinking @Popnoodles - Should do the trick.

Comment: That does do the Trick @Popnoodles. The default keyboard comes up but the Boss is ok with it. Cheers for that mate.

Comment: You can prevent that keyboard from showing too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `type="text"` instead of `type="date"`

You could also add `readonly="readonly"` to prevent the keyboard from appearing.

Comment: While that does work, adding the readonly attribute does make the input field look like it's disabled, and in chrome, the hover state is a circle with a cross through it which isn't good for user experience. I do have to account for multiple devices/browsers unfortunately.